# Cast the static types of n Implementations of an Abstract Class to correspond with their dynamic Type - with at least code as possible

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17

I have a library that works with Actors. An interface for Actor implementation is defined in the abstract class **Actor** and the actor-library works with Actor*, but in order to use another library I need to implement static functions for each class, and my actor-library naturally thinks every implementation has the static class of Actor, so in order to solve this problem I created the following variant of pointers and a wrapper for an example situation:

```cpp
ActorImpls = std::variant<
    ActorType1*,
    ActorType2*,
    ActorType3*,
    ActorType4*,
>;
```

And a cast function that reinterprets the static type to be the same of the dynamic type through checking a dynamic member field:

```cpp
  ActorImpls staticCorrespond2Dynamic(Actor* cl){
             std::string s = cl->getDynamicName();
                if(s.compare("Dynamic ActorType1")==0){
                    ActorType1* x = reinterpret_cast<ActorType1*>(cl);
                ...
```

Now I can call static functions for the given ActorImpls with a visitor, but i will always call the function with the same name, it will be ActorType1->staticFunc() or ActorType2->staticFunc(), **is there a way to make the wrapper work with less code?**

The visitor looks something like this for a static-print-func:

```cpp
struct VisitPrintStatic{
        VisitPrintStatic() {}
        void operator()(ActorType1* x){x->printStaticName();}
        ...
```

What else I have tried: implementing with variadic templates, the main problem is that getting the any info on runtime makes is almost impossible to work with. There are the folowing types of functions to consider, they have the same name through all actors:

```cpp
Actor* ActorX = new ActorTypeX;
ActorX->staticFunc() //where ActorTypeX must be reinterpreted from Actor* to ActorTypeX*
ActorTypeX::staticFunc(ActorTypeX& obj, Args...) //(same as above)
```

Comment: You could add a `virtual staticFuncWrapper() = 0;` to `Actor`, and have derived classes implement it by calling `staticFunc()`. Why again do you need each class to have a function with the same name, but can't make these functions virtual? That's a weird requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the 'overloaded()' struct/function added in C++20. Fortunately its implementation is very short, and works in C++17.

From the example at:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

```
// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>; // not needed as of C++20
```

Your calling site becomes:

```
  std::visit(overloaded {
        [](auto& actor) { StaticFun(actor); },
    }, ActorImpls);
```

Comment: I believe there is no other way to write it with less code other than this.

Comment: So do I.  I also believe this is the only sane way to use visitors.

Comment: it was not added in C++20. The comment just points out that the second line is not needed in C++20, it became a one-liner.